# What is the highest service ceiling for turboprop airplane like a Cessna 425?

Tags: fuel, altitude, turboprop

What is the highest service ceiling turboprop airplane,  that is fairly small, like maximum of 8 seats, and fairly cheap as well, not going over a million dollars. I looked at Cessna 425, and this plane has a service ceiling of 10km(33000ft), and this plane had the highest service ceiling, that fit the size and cost, that I could find.

So, basically , what plane out there has the greatest service ceiling, that  is small in size, like the Cessna 425, turboprop,  and cheap (under a million) ?

Comment: Are you asking about new cost? This is a really broad question, for example you may be able to find a used Lancair Evo for less than $1m...

Comment: @fooot I pretty much mean a plane of the size of Cessna 172 and Cessna 425. I am doing this for research purposes.

Comment: @abelenky Not sure if it matters to the op, but Turbocharged and Turboprops are pretty dissimilar.

Comment: Does it have to be a twin engine? Does it have to be turboprop?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [PA-46-500TP Malibu Meridian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Piper_PA-46) can climb to FL300 and you may be able to find a high time one for under a million.

[Socata TBM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOCATA_TBM) has a quoted ceiling of 31,000 ft and you may be able to find an older TBM 700 high time airframe for in and around a million.

In the multi-engine category:

A [PA-42 Cheyenne](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Piper_PA-42_Cheyenne) will put you up to just under 36,000 ft and can be had used for under a million.

A [Beech King Air C-90](http://beechcraft.txtav.com/en/king-air-c90gtx) will get you up to 30,000 feet and can be found used on the lower end of the price spectrum.